# Adding UIButton to the center of a UITableViewCell using Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

**The following code only shows button in the last row of the table. Any thoughts on why?**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    let button : UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 100, 24)
    button.center = self.view.center
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents:
    UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.setTitle("Click Me !", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.addSubview(button
 }
 return cell
 }
```

Comment: You have a stray brace before return cell. That should not cause this problem. Perhaps the button center should be in reference to the cell not to `self.view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
button.center = self.view.center
```

Try

```
let cellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
button.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2.0, y: cellHeight / 2.0)
```

This assumes that your tableView is full width and your cellHeight is 44.0. You can't get the actual height from the cell itself just yet. If you want the actual height you'd have to get it from the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method or do something else.

Also instead of using `self.myTable` you should use the `tableView` variable in the method itself.

Answer (score 3):

Jawwad's suggestion fixed it. For documentation here is the entire working function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {              

        var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell  

        let button : UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 100, 24)
        let cellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
        button.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2.0, y: cellHeight / 2.0)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Click Me !", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        cell.addSubview(button)

        return cell;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a Swift 3 conversion of the above answer, try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    let button : UIButton = UIButton(type:UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton

    button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 40,y :60), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 24))
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
    button.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2.0, y: cellHeight / 2.0)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.setTitle("Click Me !", for: UIControlState.normal)

    cell.addSubview(button)
    return cell
}

func buttonClicked(sender : UIButton!) {
    print("Clicked!")
}
```